# How to set flutter to specific android API level correctly

Tags: android, flutter

I have installed the latest flutter. Create a project using

```
flutter create --org test test
```

However it was created using SDK version 29 (default). I believe this is the Android API level

But I need to install my APK in Android 7 (which is API level 24). So I changed the following:

```
build.gradle
    compileSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 24
```

But it failed to build. The error message is:

> - What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
>   Android resource linking failed
>   C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a528b13ac93e64cafa3d0480e2c93207\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.

Comment: change minSdkVersion to your desired version not compileSdk

Comment: Thanks @Yadu, but the minSdkVersion is 16. When I try to install, it says `This app isn't compatible with your phone`

Comment: I get my APK from the following location `build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk`

Comment: Android 7 (Nougat)(7.0 – 7.1.2) its api level is 24 – 25.

Comment: can you debug it in studio? that error states its looking for resource and failed

Comment: @Yadu, yes and I can't delete that .gradle folder even when I shutdown everything / reboot my pc.

Comment: connect your device and do `flutter run -v`

Comment: @Yadu, I have deleted `.gradle` folder by logging in safemode. But still getting the same error after the `.gradle` folder is re-created. I have been connecting to my android simulator all these while.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue. We can only change the targetSdkVersion. compileSdkVersion leave as it is.

```
build.gradle
    compileSdkVersion 29 <- don't change
    targetSdkVersion 24
```